# Eclipse feature patch doesn't patch plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, patch

I'm trying to create a feature patch for `org.eclipse.platform` feature.

This is the feature xml:

```
<feature
      id="com.eclipse.platform.patch"
      label="MAS Eclipse Platform Patch"
      version="0.0.1.qualifier"
      provider-name="MAS">

   <requires>
      <import feature="org.eclipse.platform" version="4.22.0.v20211124-1800" patch="true"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ui.ide"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

With 4 plugins that I have in my workspace, with code changes from the original bundles. **But I've left the bundle version exactly as the originals**.

I can export the feature to a P2 site. Everything works, the feature and plugins are present.

Then, I install the feature to a just downloaded `eclipse-platform-4.22-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz` installation.
The install finish successfully, but no plugin is patched.

I have searched in StackOverflow and followed all the hint's I've found, like [Eclipse feature patch doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309535/eclipse-feature-patch-doesnt-work), or
[How to patch a feature right? (Feature-Patch gets installed without the Plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146512/how-to-patch-a-feature-right-feature-patch-gets-installed-without-the-plugin)
but still no plugin is patched.

Comment: What happens if you don't leave the bundle version exactly as the originals, accurately reflecting that they are different?

Comment: If I change the version to something "newer", say `3.10.200.v20211009-1707` compared to the original `3.10.200.v20211009-1706` it works! So I should answer my own question. But the real problem for me is the tycho build which fails in this case, because it cannot find the original bundle with `3.10.200.v20211009-1706`. But I should open another question for this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Simply using a "newer" version for the plugins, like for example `3.10.200.v20211009-1707` compared to the original `3.10.200.v20211009-1706` works.
Now the feature install also the patched plugins, alongside the original ones.

Of course some semantic version should be used to signal the patch, I think something like `3.10.201.qualifier` could be ok with Eclipse versioning rules.