# Eclipse feature patch with Maven+Tycho build

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm currently developing an Eclipse RCP application, built with Maven v3.8.4 and Tycho v2.6.0.
Everything works as expected, except a feature patch that patches the original Eclipse feature `org.eclipse.platform`.

This is feature xml:

```
<feature
      id="com.eclipse.platform.patch"
      label="MAS Eclipse Platform Patch"
      version="0.0.1.qualifier"
      provider-name="MAS">

   <requires>
      <import feature="org.eclipse.platform" version="4.22.0.v20211124-1800" patch="true"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ui.ide"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

</feature>
```

I have to set the version of the included plugins to something "newer" than the original, like described in [Eclipse feature patch doesn't patch plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254449/eclipse-feature-patch-doesnt-patch-plugins).

**BUT, with these newer versions, the tycho build fails.**

For example the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator` original version is `3.10.200.v20211009-1706`. I set it to `3.10.201.qualifier` in the MANIFEST.MF and to `3.10.201-SNAPSHOT` in the pom.xml.

And tycho complains about not find the `3.10.200.v20211009-1706` dependency:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: mas.product 0.3.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.22.0.v20211124-1800 requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui.navigator [3.10.200.v20211009-1706,3.10.200.v20211009-1706]' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: mas.product 0.3.0.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 0.0.0
```

I believe this must be something related to this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389698
am I right?

Any solutions or even workaround?
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in my case at least, upgrading to tycho v0.2.7 fix the problem. Now the build gives some warnings about the dependencies:

```
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-repository-plugin:2.7.0:assemble-repository (default-assemble-repository) @ com.marchesini.mas.app.releng.product ---
[WARNING] Following dependencies were not found by the slicer (you can disregard this if it is intentional):
Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.22.0.v20211124-1800 to org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring [3.12.0.v20210618-1953,3.12.0.v20210618-1953].
Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.22.0.v20211124-1800 to org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui.navigator [3.10.200.v20211009-1706,3.10.200.v20211009-1706].
Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.22.0.v20211124-1800 to org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources [3.8.300.v20210914-2004,3.8.300.v20210914-2004].
Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.22.0.v20211124-1800 to org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui.ide [3.18.400.v20211026-0701,3.18.400.v20211026-0701].
```

but at least it doesn't fail!